# how to dynamically change textView's superview height as textView's height increases

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, textview, superview

I have a textView at the bottom of my screen which is a subView of a containerView.  This is the text input section of a chat app.  I would like to know how to increase the size of the textView's container view as the text view size increases.  I am using autolayout.  I have used the following textView delegate method to resize the textView and it seems to work fine.  But the container view does not change size regardless of what I try.  Thank you.

> ```
> func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
>     messageTextView.frame.size.height = messageTextView.contentSize.height
>     return true
> }
> ```

Comment: try  messageTextView.sizeToFit()

Comment: hi.  thanks.  I tried this in the above method but it didn't change anything.

Comment: sure, try adding also messageTextView.layoutIfNeeded() after sizeToFit()

Comment: i tried that as well.  The textview is contained within it's superview but the superview size does not changed.  I did this for both the message text view as well as the message text view's superview.  both cases failed to change anything.

Comment: maybe something with messageTextView.superView!.frame.size...

Comment: yes, tried that as well.  Not really sure why nothing is working.  Seems it's not resizing superview in any scenario

Comment: i think this is such a common scenario.  it is in iMessage and most other chat apps.  Not sure how they go about this

Comment: can you please provide more code? maybe the class your class

Comment: actually I created a new project with just a textview inside another view.  and the only code is the delegate method above.  the behaviour is the same as in my app.  so that is all the code above.  the rest are the constraints in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  I solved this by simply not putting the textView inside another view.  I still have the two views in the same position but they are both just subview's of the main view.  Neither one is inside the other.  Then changing the height of each view by the contentSize.height of the textView works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same func that works for me:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    var height = self.noteValueLabel!.contentSize;
    textView.sizeToFit();

        super.frame.size.height+=textView.frame.maxY - super.frame.height + 3.0;
    }
```

it works for me, when noteValueLabel is the UITextView
and super.frame.size is yours messageTextView

Comment: i just tried this and it works for the superview.  the size seems to increase as expected.  but now my textView is not increasing.  I added the code above.

Comment: that is not working.  the textView size remains fixed.  I wonder if it's my constraints in storyboard.  at the moment i have the height of the textview to be >= 50.  But it remains at 50.

Comment: I guess it's the constraints, I'm not using them at all. not using storyboard it's just make everything too complicated than it is

anyway, can't help more than that I guess, sorry (:

Comment: i appreciate the help.  I'll keep plugging away.  At least you helped me to increase the container view size.  halfway there...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone still looking for the answer, I solved my issue by setting my textView's Layout property to `Autoresizing Mask` in size inspector

[image]